# "type annotations required" while using RustFFT

Tags: compiler-errors, rust

I have a problem with the following code

```
extern crate num;
extern crate rustfft;

use rustfft::num_complex::Complex;
use rustfft::num_traits::Zero;

pub fn ct_fft(input: &Vec<f64>, sampling: u32) {
    let data_size = input.len();

    let mut input_array: Vec<Complex<f64>> = Vec::with_capacity(data_size);

    let fft = rustfft::FFTplanner::new(false).plan_fft(data_size as usize);

    for v in input {
        input_array.push(Complex { re: *v, im: 0.0 });
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `_: rustfft::FFTnum`
  --> src/ctdsp.rs:19:15
   |
19 |     let fft = rustfft::FFTplanner::new(false).plan_fft(data_size as usize);
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: required by `<rustfft::FFTplanner<T>>::new`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I don't understand why I got this error; I was using RustFFT earlier and it worked with no problems and I'm using it exactly the same way. I cannot find any information about this error in regard to RustFFT.

Rust version:

```
╰─$ rustc --version                                                                               
rustc 1.26.0-nightly (9c9424de5 2018-03-27)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library, but at a guess: you never *use* `fft`, or (seemingly) tie it to any other type.  It's like if you write `vec![]`, but never put anything in it: the compiler can't know what type you wanted to use.

Comment: Actually... when i processed data (`fft.process(&mut input_array, &mut output_array);` it started to work properly... So, rust can figure out type form context?

Comment: That *is* how type inference works: deduce types from usage.  If you don't use a thing, there's nothing for the compiler to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (from your comments) is that you weren't using `fft`.  Rust can infer types, but it can only do so if there's enough context.  If you never use `fft`, the compiler doesn't have enough information to work out what the complete type is supposed to be.

Remember, every variable in Rust has a single, complete type.  It's just that in some cases, Rust can work it out by itself and lets you omit the type.  This is not one of those cases.

Comment: thanks, that clarifies A LOT. I jumped into rust from several years of C. The most type guessing i had was __auto_type extension...